# Selecting the data that isn't in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all of the posts that are not marked as read by the user.

tbl_post

```
post_id    post_message
1           hello world
2           good night
3           good morning
4           incredible 
5           cool
```

tbl_mark_as_read

```
user_id      post_id
3             1
3             4
```

I want to select all data that will not be selected in this query

```
SELECT p.post_id,p.post_message FROM tbl_post AS p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_mark_as_read AS r
ON r.post_id = p.post_id
AND r.user_id = 3
```

I want the output to be like

```
post_id       post_message
2              good night
3              good morning
5              cool
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_post
WHERE  post_in NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM tbl_mark_as_read);
```

If you want to exclude only the posts that user 3 has read, you can add a `where` clause to the inner query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_post
WHERE  post_in NOT IN (SELECT post_id 
                       FROM   tbl_mark_as_read 
                       WHERE  user_id = 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.post_id,p.post_message FROM tbl_post AS p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_mark_as_read AS r
ON r.post_id = p.post_id
AND r.user_id = 3
where r is null
```